# How can I validate wpf bindings are going to real properties?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unit-testing

I would like a simple way to ensure that all bindings I've declared in my xaml files go to real properties.  Even better, I'd like to instantiate my wpf window in a unit test and call a method to ensure that the bindings are correct.

Unfortunately, wpf doesn't even throw an exception if I have something wrong.  That leaves me the burden to "discover" problems during a QA phase.

Does anyone know of a way I can better validate my bindings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suboptimal way would be to search through the visual tree for all dependency properties, and then check:

```
var bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(dependencyObject, dependencyProperty);

if (bindingExpression != null)
{
    var status = bindingExpression.Status;
}
```

If the `status` is `Unattached` then the expression hasn't resolved.

Of course, you wouldn't want to do this in a production app, but it might make sense in a debug or integration test scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Data binding errors show up in the Visual Studio Output window.  For example, say I want to bind a TextBlock to the Title property of a Window but I mistype "Title" as "Ritle".  I will see this in the output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'Ritle' property not found on 'object' ''MessageWindow' (Name='Window')'. BindingExpression:Path=Ritle; DataItem='MessageWindow' (Name='Window'); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='WindowTitle'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

You can get more control over how these messages are reported by using Trace Sources.  [This article](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52) by Bea Stollnitz describes this in greater detail.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but that doesn't really validate your bindings. It just provides debug info that the developer has to scrutinize. I think an attempt to write a TraceListener that throws when it "discovers" a binding error would be rather fragile, given that it would have to parse messages that could change at Microsoft's whim. Probably better than nothing, though.